# JWT Signature validation failed

Tags: c#, .net, jwt

I am getting a very strange error when validating a JWT signature, this works fine when running the web application locally however when deployed to the server I receive this error:

"message: IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey\r\n'.\nExceptions caught:\n ''.\ntoken: '{\"typ\":\"JWT\",\"alg\":\"HS256\"}.....

I create my token like this

```
var securityKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret);

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    // Token Creation
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = identity,
        TokenIssuerName = "self",                
        AppliesToAddress = "http://example.com",
        Lifetime = new Lifetime(now, now.AddMinutes(2)),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
     new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(securityKey),
     "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha256",
     "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"),
    };
    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

    return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

And validate like this:

```
        // Create token validation parameters for the signed JWT
        // This object will be used to verify the cryptographic signature of the received JWT
        TokenValidationParameters validationParams =
            new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidAudience = "http://example.com",
                ValidIssuer = "self",
                IssuerSigningToken = new BinarySecretSecurityToken(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret)),
            };

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        //   tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParams);

        SecurityToken st;
        principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParams, out st);
        return true;
```

The error occurs when calling "token.ValidateToken(..)"

Any ideas?